# Javascript: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am experiencing an issue. I am working with a fairly old application which has the following logic:

```
var Page;
var OriginalSubmit;

function init() {
    Page = document.forms[0];
    OriginalSubmit = Page.submit;
    Page.submit = newPageSubmit;
}

function newPageSubmit() {
  validate();
  OriginalSubmit();
}
```

When the OriginalSubmit is executed, I get an Illegal invocation argument. I've read enough to understand that is because the this reference has changed (at least I think that's the case), but what I am struggling with is the correct way to fix it. The JavaScript for this is a mess, wrapped up with JSPs and global functions everywhere, so making this correct would be quite an effort, so I am looing to see if there's a chance for a less invasive solution, thanks.

Comment: OriginalSubmit = Page.submit.bind(Page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `OriginalSubmit = Page.submit` you're obtaining a reference to the `.submit()` function, but when you call it as just plain `OriginalSubmit()` you're losing the `Page` context variable that will be passed as `this` to that function:

```
myObject.method();  // calls "method" with "this === myObject"

var method = myObject.method();
method();           // calls "method" with "this === window"
```

Instead, use this:

```
OriginalSubmit.call(Page);    // sets "this" to "Page"
```

Note that even then, it's possible that re-assigning a method of a native DOM element won't work portably in all browsers, and may not work at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this does seem to work. I realize it's not the correct solution, but given the nature of this site, this might be the way to go for now.