# IE8 Form Submission

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

in reference to my previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343676/javascript-illegal-invocation), one detail I left out is that this needs to work on IE8, which doesn't support the bind function. I did some research, and found references to using Modernizr to add the bind polyfill. The problem is that when I execute this on IE8, I get an error that the object doesn't support bind. Upon inspecting the Page.submit value, I discovered that IE think this is an object, not a function. I am curious to know if this is expected behavior, and if so, what would be some recommendations on approaches?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Illegal invocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343676/javascript-illegal-invocation)

Comment: To improve/clarify your question, use the "edit" link under the question, don't post a new question.

Comment: Just a tip: you should excerpt your previous question here so that people don't need to read the previous question to understand what you're asking here.